# JNI_CreateJavaVM on linux destroys stack?

Tags: linux, jvm, stack, java-native-interface

This is happening on linux 2.6.18-238.5.1.el5 with a 64 bit app. My process stack size is 10MB. However, after a (successful) call to JNI_CreateJavaVM I only seem to have 1-2 MB left on the stack. If I got past it - I get memory fault as if I'm overflowing the stack.

A few notes:

1. If I DON'T create a JVM then I get have access to the whole my my 10MB stack.
2. The same test program with the same makefile runs fine on Solaris even with a call to JVM

Test source:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void CreateVM(JavaVM ** jvm) {

    JNIEnv *env;
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    JavaVMOption options[1];
    options[0].optionString = (char*)"-Xcheck:jni";

    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    vm_args.nOptions = 0;
    vm_args.options = options;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = 0;

    int ret = JNI_CreateJavaVM(jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
    if(ret < 0) {
        printf("\nUnable to Launch JVM\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ( env->ExceptionCheck() == JNI_TRUE ) {
        printf("exception\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void f() {
    printf("inside...\n");
    //eat up a few megs of stack
    char stackTest[0x2FFFFF];
    printf("...returning");
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    JavaVM * jvm;
    CreateVM(&jvm);

    f();

    printf("exiting...\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Build command:

> g++ -m64 CTest.cpp -I/import/bitbucket/JDK/jdk1.6.0_26/include -I/import/bitbucket/JDK/jdk1.6.0_26/include/linux -L/import/bitbucket/JDK/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/amd64 -L/import/bitbucket/JDK/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljava -ljvm

Comment: Can you do an `strace -f a.out` and post  results in the internet?

Answer (score 0):

Your stack-eater seems buggy, but it is not if -O0 is used

Also, JVM on sun can vary or it can use less stack space when it runs on solaris.

How did you limit stack size on Linux and Solaris?

Update: Yes, JVM uses [different settings on OS Solaris and OS Linux:](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html)

> -XX:ThreadStackSize=512   Thread Stack Size (in Kbytes). (0 means use default stack size) [Sparc: 512; Solaris x86: 320 (was 256 prior in 5.0 and earlier); Sparc 64 bit: 1024; Linux amd64: 1024 (was 0 in 5.0 and earlier); all others 0.]

I don't know is this setting about main thread, but this indicates that solaris jvm will use different settings for memory than linux amd64 jvm.

=== UPDATE2

the very first operations in JNI_CreateJavaVM are [thread creation](http://www.google.com/codesearch#nd3OyX9_ZiE/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp&q=JNI_CreateJavaVM&exact_package=http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot&type=cs&l=3278) because JVM itself is highly threaded:

```
  result = Threads::create_vm((JavaVMInitArgs*) args, &can_try_again);
  if (result == JNI_OK) {
    JavaThread *thread = JavaThread::current();
    /* thread is thread_in_vm here */
    *vm = (JavaVM *)(&main_vm);
```

So, thread is created in call of `CreateJavaVM`

Change "CompilerThreadStackSize" global variable, because (!!!!!!!!!AAA I lost all sources I added to answer!!! Why no draft-autosave when editing????)

On [AMD64 Linux, JVM has 4M](http://www.google.com/codesearch#Ij0h1PFjHKo/src/os_cpu/linux_x86/vm/os_linux_x86.cpp&q=jdk7%20default_stack_size&type=cs&l=617) compiler thread stack by default and [Solaris SPARC64's has 2M](http://www.google.com/codesearch#Ij0h1PFjHKo/src/os/solaris/vm/os_solaris.cpp&type=cs&l=1164) compiler thread stack by default. Usual threads got 1M stacks on linux and 2M stacks on Solaris.

Use [1](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4864683) to limit compiler stack size on linux

> -XX:CompilerThreadStackSize to adjust the stack size

the value is in kb. Try to set it to 2048 on both OS.

Comment: Why is my stack eater buggy? I monitor the stack use with pmap which tells me the stack is correctly allocated for the variable.

Comment: I'm using the deafult stack limits on my solaris and linux boxes as shown by ulimit -s.

Comment: Is it the same on linux and solaris? Your stack eater may be optimized by compiler (the variable is not used, so it can be not allocated). Is the compiler the same on linux and solaris?

Comment: Is your solaris 32 or 64? sparc or x86?

Comment: Regarding thread stack size for the JVM I've experimented with different sizes to no avail. Anyway it should not matter much since I'm not creating any new threads or executing any piece of java code. All I'm doing is creating the JVM. Bot systems are 64bit linux is x86 and solaris is sparcv9.

Comment: The variable is not optimized. Again, I can see the stack usage using pmap. Anyway the attached code is not the issue but a testcase to illustrate the issue. The issue is our application that crashes on linux after it eats 1-2 MB into the stack whereas on Solaris runs fine. Unfortunately rewriting the application to effectively use 1-2 MB of stack is not an option for us. The compiler is the same, gcc, see the included build command.

Comment: Ya, included build command is for linux because on "1.6.0_26/include/linux" in it. When yo did create a JVM, how can it limit the stack size available to program (it is just a call which will return into main)? I think, Creating JVM means starting some JVM threads, which will allocate stacks. The option is to make stack limit higher. There can be another stack-allocated data in JVM, which depends on your OS. Please, add full build command for both OSes in Q and add output of `g++ --version`

Comment: Here is the build command for Solaris. It's almost the same as linux the only thing that is different are jdk jni directory paths. 
g++ -m64 CTest.cpp -I/opt/installs/java/jdk1.6.0_16/include -I/opt/installs/java/jdk1.6.0_16/include/solaris -L/opt/installs/java/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/lib/sparcv9 -L/opt/installs/java/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/lib/sparcv9 -ljava -ljvm

Comment: Linux: g++ (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: Solaris: g++ (GCC) 3.4.3 (csl-sol210-3_4-branch+sol_rpath)
Copyright (C) 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: I'm not sure what this is and what it has to do with the issue. I tried it just to say I did but needless to say it doesn't change a thing.

Comment: Ya, Sorry, your phrase is hard to understand. Please, add option  `-XX:CompilerThreadStackSize=1024` or =2048 and check, how much stack is available in Linux. I think, this can help.

Comment: Which part is hard to understand? The one where I'm saying that I don't know what this option is for and how it relates to my problem? Or the one where I say that I tried it and it made no difference?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Now I can reproduce a SIGSEGV in `f()`; I use i386 jvm, and a bit older. Let's debug the memory allocation.

```
$ cat gdb.how
b main
r
b mmap
commands
x/x $sp+4
x/x $sp+8
bt
c
end
c
```

You may change a `$sp+4` and `$sp+8` to  +8 and +16 or like. First outputs from gdb should look like "00000000,  00001000". I suggest you have debuging symbols for jvm (I do).

```
$ gdb  -x gdb.how ./a.out  > gdb.log
quit
y
```

Now, lets view, how memory is allocated for threads:

```
$ grep Breakpoint\ 2, -A4 gdb.log | grep pthread_create -B 2 | grep 0x00 |cut -d : -f 2 |
perl -e '$a=0;while(<>){s/0x0//;$a+=$_;};print "ibase=16\n".uc($a)."\n";'|bc
4616192
```

It is sum of all thread's stack sizes. You can delete some parts of this command to view the real allocations, I have 7 threads created with Sun JVM.

Now you can try to change some options and check, how much memory was allocated to threads stacks.

What I get... This is interesting. I have `ulimit -s` as 8192.
If I do start of the `./a.out` with `./a.out`, I got a SEGV

```
$ ./a.out
Segmentation fault
```

But if I do start as `(./a.out )` (start in bash-subshell); there is no Segmentation fault.

Comment: Found some articles that thought old may confirm that the JVM indeed restricts the size of the main thread to 2MB. At least for linux it may still be a hard limit, supposedly due to the thread library.

Comment: Hi. I cant understand, why `ulimit -s` does a SIGSEGV. Main thread (your function main) stack is small (3.5-4 MB); additional thread's stacks are not counted in checking for RLIMIT_STACK (nptl and kernel sources checked). May be the SEGV is from another `ulimit`, not the stack's one?

Comment: Ya, please do run of "`/lib*/libc.so.6`" and `grep -i` for NPTL or LinuxThreads. There will be version of threading library and version of glibc itself (in the first line). Please, post both versions here or in the question.

Comment: Got NPTL 2.5. I'm not seeing LiuxThreads, only pthreads. From what I'm seeing (and what the articles I've found seem to be confirming) JVM completely ignores any limits you may have set for your main thread, be it through ulimit -s or even setrlimit(). I've tried setrlimit, the function call completes successfully with no errors but the stack remains restricted to 2MB.